# Построить строку форматирования на основе URL параметров

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Изучал регулярные вытажения по надобности и столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть строка `text='event=20&page=1&event'`, на выходе пытаюсь получить `text='event=20&page=%s&event'`, то есть заменить именно эту цифру `1` на `%s`.

Пытался делать через функцию re.sub:

```
text='event=20&page=1&event' 
new_text = re.sub(r"/page=(\d+)/$", '%s', text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем вам эти странные `/` и `$` здесь нужны? Черточки долой, конец строки тоже.

Забыл как выкидывать строку из поиска, поэтому с небольшим хаком вариант:

```
new_text = re.sub(r"\bpage=(\d+)", 'page=%s', text)
```

`\b` - чтобы строки типа `current_page` отбросить

**UPD:**

Нашел как отбросить строку из поиска:

```
new_text = re.sub(r"(?<=\bpage=)(\d+)", '%s', text)
```

Конструкция вида `(?<=шаблон)шаблон_для_поиска` используется для позитивного просмотра назад, подробнее лучше почитать в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4)

И еще - меня несколько смущает наличие у вас и отсутствие у меня конца строки в поиске. Может быть вы хотели указать не конец строки, а конец слова? Т.е. `page=123a` не должно заменяться на `page=%sa`? Тогда надо несколько изменить регулярку:

```
new_text = re.sub(r"(?<=\bpage=)(\d+)\b", '%s', text)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это я сам себя загнал в тупик решив заменить 1 на %s, можно же было и 'page=%s' захватить на замену, сам напридумывал проблем

Comment: @AlexeyA, всегда пожалуйста ))

Обновил ответ - добавил еще один вариант, который как раз отбрасывает ненужный нам `page=` из замены

Answer (score 2):

В Питоне есть парсер для таких (url query) строк:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

query_string = 'event=20&page=1&event'
params = parse_qs(query_string, keep_blank_values=True)
# -> {'event': ['20', ''], 'page': ['1']}
```

Если порядок важен, то можно использовать `parse_qsl()` функцию, которая возвращает список пар:
имя -> значение.

Чтобы собрать новый запрос, вместо строкового форматирования `%s`, можно использовать `urlencode()`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

params['page'] = ['what&ever']
new_query_string = urlencode(params, doseq=True)
# -> 'event=20&event=&page=what%26ever'
```

Если есть возможность, то следует использовать специализированные инструменты по сравнению с более общими регулярными выражениями и строковым форматированием, чтобы не изобретать велосипед.

В Python 2 эти функции в других модулях: `urlparse.parse_qs()`, `urllib.urlencode()`.